# Replace all instances of string in page (including header and footer)

Tags: php, content

I created a small plugin, with a function to replace some strings with others.

```
function replace_text($text) {
    $text = str_replace('look-for-this-string', 'replace-with-this-string', $text);
    $text = str_replace('look-for-that-string2', 'replace-with-that-string2', $text);
    return $text;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'replace_text');
```

It works for most of the content, but not for header, footer, etc.
Is there any way to do that?